# How to find the coverage of a library opened using dlopen()?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, dlopen, gcov

I have a C++ library (.so) which is opened using dlopen() by another application. But I need to find the code coverage of this library while run within the application using gcov. Is it possible? If yes, how can it be done?

If not, how can the issue be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have your compiled your C++ library with the `--coverage` flag?  I've never actually used a '.so' library with gcov before, so I'm not sure it would work anyway.

Secondly could you arrange a test version of your application to not use `dlopen()`, but instead be linked to a static library(.a) version of your library and still make the usual calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Coverage of shared library loaded by `dlopen` can be generated.

1) compile shared library with flags `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`

2) compile program that using `dlopen` with flags `-fprofile-arc -ftest-coverage`

3) lcov to generate `.info` file

```sh
lcov --capture --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 --directory path/to/.gcda --output-file coverage.info
```

4) generate html

```sh
genhtml coverage.info --branch-coverage --output-directory out
```